# Change Toolbar title while having SearchView

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview

I've a toolbar and I want to change it's Title. 
At first, I've a SearchView in it, so I add `SearchView` to toolbar like this:

```
private void setupSearchView() {
    mSearchView = new SearchView(this);     
    searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

    mSearchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
}
```

Then I set `Toolbar`

```
private void setupSearchToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    } 
}
```

At this point, I'd like to remove `SearchView` and add title. I tried

First approach: `this.setTitle(title)`

Second approach:

```
private void setupToolbar() {
     Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) 
     findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar); 

     if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
         getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
     }
 }
```

I can get rid of `SearchView` with `mSearchView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`, but then calling `setupToolbar()` still doesn't change anything.

Xml structure:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar/>
    </AppBarLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inflate "Search Item" as menu item,

add this menu file in res/menu directory:

menu_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:iconTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</menu>
```

In setupSearchTooBar() method inflate it like this,

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menuitem)
```

and in SetUpSearchView()

```
mSearchItem = (MenuItem) toobar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_search)
mSearchView = (SearchView) mSearchItem.getActionView()
```

Now set title either this.title = "your title" or toolbar.title = "your title"

I hope this will Help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this `setupToolbar()` as below

```
Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;

private void setupToolbar() {
    mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mActionBarToolbar.setTitle("My title");
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar); 
    mSearchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
}
```

and create a function to change Title as

```
private void changeTitle(String newTitle){
    mSearchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
    mActionBarToolbar.setTitle(newTitle);
}
```

Comment: This does not help. SearchView is still visible and title is not seen.